# EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file when loading several files in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have 1000 csv files that I call using the following code (which puts every file into a dictionary):

```
dataframes = {}
csv_root = Path(".")
for csv_path in csv_root.glob("*.csv"):
key = csv_path.stem
dataframes[key] = pd.read_csv(csv_path, skiprows=1)
```

However when I use this code I got this error

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Which indicates that there is empty data or header is encountered.

I would like to know how to identify which of those 1000 csv files are the ones causing troubles? Because, as you can understand, checking file by file will consume a lot of time.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a try/catch, like so:

```
dataframes = {}
csv_root = Path(".")
for csv_path in csv_root.glob("*.csv"):
    key = csv_path.stem
    try:
        dataframes[key] = pd.read_csv(csv_path, skiprows=1)
    except Exception, as e:
        dataframes[key] = 'error' # mark the errored
```

This last step will get you the stems with issues:

```
errored_stems = [k for k,v in dataframes.iteritems() if k == 'error']
```

Comment: Thank @Brandon but When I used the stems code I get the following error: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'". It seems its a problem of the python version, but I dont know how to solve it. Can you help me?